# Firebase Analytics not tracking the name of my app screens: Screen name (not set)

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using last version of Firebase with Analytics to track screen openings on an app. I'm checking on Firebase that the screen openings are being tracked but they only are showing the activity Java class name under the "Screen class" table. If I switch to "Screen name" then (not set) is displayed. No screen names are being tracked.

I tried two ways I find on the official documentation and here in Stack Overflow:

Way 1:

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(SectionManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity(), name, null /* class override */);
```

Way 2:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "screen");
params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_ITEM, params);
```

I double checked that `name` variable contains the real name of the screen.

None of them work. I can't seem to solve it checking on other questions here and also checking the official documentation.

Comment: Are you calling `setCurrentScreen()` in an Activity lifecycle method? Which one?  I notice this in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens): _The screen name and screen class stay the same until the Activity changes_.

Comment: @BobSnyder yes I'm calling just before doing the startActivity call, but.. is that a problem? then why is registering the event ?

Comment: As you can see they don't tell you to track it in an activity event: "Manually tracking screens is useful if your app does not use a separate Activity for each screen you may wish to track, such as in a game"

Comment: Also this: "The screen name and screen class stay the same until the Activity changes or you make a new call to setCurrentScreen()."

Comment: I hadn't used `setCurrentScreen()` until I saw this question.  As an experiment, I added it to `onResume()` of an activity.  I saw the screen name I assigned included in Analytics logcat messages., and after a number of hours (12+) the name appeared in the `screen_view` event data of the Firebase console.

Comment: `setCurrentScreen()` event should be pushed from `onResume()` method only. Otherwise it will not show name of screen in report, it will only show class name of screen.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you forget to initialize `mFirebaseAnalytics` you need to initialize it on onCreate method first and make sure that you call `mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(..)` after this initialization check out how to initialize on each screen

```
// [START declare_analytics]
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
// [END declare_analytics]

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // here the initialization of instance
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
}
```

tell me if this answer is working for you or not , or you can also update code snipit in your question that i can do proper analysis on this issue,
thanks